# Can you factor out a known Brownian Motion during integration?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales, markov-process

Say I have a problem which is of the form, where $W(t)$ is a Brownian Motion and $f(a,b)$ is just some function where we will plug in terms $u, W(u)$. For this example, let's say that $f(a,b) = b-a^2b$. If I have the following form:

$$
\int^{t}_0 W(t)f\big(u,W(u)\big)dW(u),
$$

would I be able to take out the $W(t)$ and treat it as if it were a constant so that we have the form

$$
W(t)\int^{t}_0 f\big(u,W(u)\big)dW(u)?
$$

If not how would I go about solving such a problem?

Comment: Im not sure if I totally understand the first integral. Do you mean with W(t) Brownian Motion at time t? With respect to what filtration would this be defined? If the standard brownian filtration is chosen, then you run into measurability issues, since the process you want to integrate is not even adapted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that I see with the first integral is that it might not be well-defined. Following Øksendal, Definition 3.1.4, the integrand, let us call it $F(s,\omega)$ with $s:=u$, must satisfy,

2. $F(s,\omega)$ is $\mathcal{F}_s$-adapted, i.e., $\omega\to   
       F(s,\omega)$ must be $\mathcal{F}_s$ measurable for all $s$, where $\mathcal{F}_s$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the Brownian motion up to $s$, Definition 3.1.2 Øksendal.

Clearly, this does not seem to be the case for your integral, as it depends on $W(t)$ with $t\ge s$ for all $s$.